# Common Lisp function returning the wrong value

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying the project euler problems to learn common lisp and I'm stuck pretty early.  On  problem 1, the question is the sum of integers from 1 to 1000.  I think the code below should do it, but it always returns the value of `end` (if it's mod 3 or mod 5) or 0 instead.

```
(defun mod3or5 (n)                                                                 
  (cond                                                                            
    ((equal (mod n 5) 0) n)                                                        
    ((equal (mod n 3) 0) n)                                                        
    (0))))                                                                         

(defun mod-sum (start end)                                                         
  (cond                                                                            
    ((equal start end) (mod3or5 start))                                            
    (+ (mod3or5 start) (mod-sum (+ start 1) end))))
```

For example

```
(mod-sum 1 9)
=> 9
(mod-sum 1 8)
=> 0
```

I would expect the answers to be 23 and 14 respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each form given to `cond` has the form `(condition exp1 ... expn)`. If `condition` is true, it will evaluate all the expressions and return the value of `expn`. If `condition` is false, it will continue with the next form.

Your last form is this: `(+ (mod3or5 start) (mod-sum (+ start 1) end))`. So here `+` is the condition (which will always be true because `+` is a function and thus not `nil`), `(mod3or5 start)` is the first expression (which will be evaluated, but not returned) and `(mod-sum (+ start 1) end)` is the last expression (which will be evaluated and then returned).

"Else branches" in `cond` are implemented by choosing `t` as the condition. So your last form should look like this:

```
(t (+ (mod3or5 start) (mod-sum (+ start 1) end)))
```

Comment: And in mod3or5 0 is returned "accidentally" (if there's no value clause(s), the test value is returned and 0 is non-nil, so true).

Answer (score 0):

I've posted this before, but it was in Scheme, so I decided to rewrite it in a bit, using `loop` for a change:

```
(defun euler-1 ()
  (loop with x = (list 3 2 1 3 1 2 3)
     for i in (nconc x x)
     while (< (+ steps i) 1000)
     summing i into steps
     summing steps into result
     finally (return result)))
```

This is how you could do it, avoiding modulo'ing (because it is expensive). You would also step 2 numbers on average (skipping those you don't have to add).